# Should Neosporin never be used?

Tags: allergy, wound-care, neosporin, antibiotic-cream

I read on https://millerfamilydermatology.com/things-that-are-forbidden-in-my-house/  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171020215827/https://millerfamilydermatology.com/things-that-are-forbidden-in-my-house/)):

> ## 1 Neosporin®
>
> Neosporin is a combination of 3 different topical antibiotics-Neomycin
> Sulfate, Polymyxin B and Bacitracin Zinc.  They say you should use it
> on “every cut, every time” and claim that it will heal cuts and
> scrapes in half the time.  There are two reasons why I have banned
> Neosporin from my house.
>
> First, non-infected wounds don’t heal any faster with Neosporin than
> with vaseline, at least not in any credible study that was performed
> by a 3rd party instead of a drug company.  When it comes to simple
> wound healing, washing the wound with soap and water and then keeping
> it covered with Vaseline is king.  Many products claim faster wound
> healing, but there aren’t any randomized controlled trials that show a
> better response than vaseline.  Can you think of an easier study to
> do?
>
> Second, Neomycin sulfate was allergen of the year in 2010.  Bacitracin
> was allergen of the year in 2003.  With repeated usage, about 10% of
> people will develop allergy to either of these topical antibiotics.
> Using them on open wounds on the legs is particularly prone to cause
> allergy to develop.  When allergies to these antibiotics occur,
> patients develop a poison ivy like reaction on areas where they use
> them (like what you see in the photograph featured in this blog post).
> In addition, some patients with bacitracin allergy have developed
> anaphylactic shock.  Patients with severe neomycin allergies are
> unable to receive some vaccines.
>
> I never use Neosporin and see no reason to ever use it.​

Should Neosporin never be used?

Answer (score 5):

You can look up practically any medicine that exists and you will find long lists of all of the possible side effects, risks and interactions.

Manufacturers have to list everything that could possibly go wrong, in order to cover their butts legally, in this "*Caution: Coffee May Be Hot!*" world that we live in.  Medical companies have to do [extensive testing](https://www.fda.gov/drugs/resourcesforyou/consumers/ucm143531.htm) of every product and document possible side effects that might not even be related.  The U.S. spends [$55 billion/year](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3048809/) on liability insurance.

Neosporin (aka Polysporin where I live) is something I always keep on hand. The tiniest scrape could become infected if not kept clean.  Use it sparingly and a tube lasts for years.

During that time, the sun is damaging you more than the eating a tube of Neosporin would!  Neosporin is [0.0004%](https://www.drugs.com/pro/neosporin.html) medicine and the other 99.9994% is basically [Vaseline](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-69007-0_136) (to keep it from rubbing off, and as an inert germ barrier.

---

@Prince states "[Neosporin] is said to speed up healing but [most](http://www.care2.com/greenliving/4-reasons-to-throw-your-neosporin-in-the-garbage.html) cases **prove** that Neosporin is actually one of the antibacterial ointments behind the spread of a lethal strain of MRSA".

The "evidence" provided is a lone link to an article written by a [self-proclaimed bee-keeping entrepreneur](https://twitter.com/maryamhenein?lang=en) with no medical background, whose primary cause appears to be promoting a movie she directed.

### **Let's walk through the article's "proof" piece by piece:**

- Antibiotic resistance (MRSA) is bad.  It has even killed people.  The example given: like vulnerable babies & elderly in India.
- the author is allergic to one antimicrobial ingredient in Neosporin. This allergy affect [3%](https://www.verywell.com/sulfa-drug-allergy-83067) of people, which "*is similar rate as allergies to other antibiotics, such as penicillin*".
- The referenced 'study' *"Antimicrobial Ointments and Methicillin-
  Resistant Staphylococcus aureus USA300"* [mentions Neosporin only once](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/pdfs/10-1365-ahead_of_print.pdf), stating that in some cases, patients tried to treat MRSA with only large amounts of Neosporin -- *which didn't cure them*.  I guess that proves there should be a warning on the tube: "*Neosporin will not cure life threatening infections. If you have one, see a doctor.*"
- When animals eat antibiotics and then humans eat animals, traces of antibiotics might show up in the humans.
- **My favorite part** is her tangent about how "in ancient times" people thought consuming Silver would fight infection.  Later they realized eating Silver didn't cure them and instead caused different problems.  Then **in the very next paragraph** she recommends using Silver Oxide instead of Neosporin.  The only application of Silver Oxide states in Wikipedia is use as *an ingredient in batteries*.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_oxide
- The article's only link from a doctor is a two-page opinion *essay* (far from clinical evidence) written by a single doctor stating that people sometimes think they can use Neosporin to treat major illnesses instead of seeing their doctor, including one idiot who's foot was almost amputated after treating a visibly disgusting infection with nothing but Neosporin once a day.  **Note the category in which the essay is classified** (below the document):  ***Entertainment & Humor***

So, **using the same logic as the author's case against Neosporin**:

1. Gun-crimes kill a lot of people
2. Nerf guns are a readily-available, gentler form of a gun but sometimes people misuse them and get hurt.
3. Therefore nobody should ever use Nerf Guns. That will **solve** the gun-crime problem.

Or one more:

1. If you have HIV, eating lots of bubblegum doesn't cure you.
2. Therefore, bubblegum is responsible for the HIV epidemic.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Comment: Good to know; that is an excellent policy!  I do a lot of wiki edits so I *am* in the habit of citing every claim - but SE wouldn't let me yet! Thus, I had to remove 3 links, but guess I can post them here...

- ["...$55 billion/year on liability insurance" (Nat Library of Medicine)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3048809/)
- ["What happens in Clinical Trials?" (US FDA)](https://www.fda.gov/drugs/resourcesforyou/consumers/ucm143531.htm)
- ["Vaseline as an occlusive topical for wound care" (Springer Science)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-69007-0_136)

Comment: @ashleedawg You can ping me in [The Waiting Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22477/the-waiting-room) once you got another 10 reputation, or any other of my chat rooms.

Comment: @ashleedawg - Welcome to the site! If you take a look, every site has a [help section available](https://health.stackexchange.com/help) where you can see how to best ask and answer questions and the rules specific to each site. Also, once you get higher rep overall, you will get 100 points "association bonus" on any new site. you join. Again, welcome! :)

Answer (score 4):

Neosporin has its advantages but also has way too many disadvantages. It is said to speed up healing but [most](http://www.care2.com/greenliving/4-reasons-to-throw-your-neosporin-in-the-garbage.html) cases prove that Neosporin is actually one of the antibacterial ointments behind the spread of a lethal strain of MRSA ([methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus](http://www.webmd.com/parenting/news/20110914/study-antibiotic-ointments-may-spread-of-mrsa%20)) called USA 300.

So it'll be highly recommended to resist and desist from the use of Neosporin.